# Замена текста на JQuery

Tags: jquery, php, html, javascript

Скажите, кто знает, как можно заменить '>' на '&gt;' в блоке с текстом?

Answer (score 2):

PHP вам показал [[@ROOT](/users/4208/root)](/users/4208/root). Если на JS, то так

```
var str = "adcdefg>abcdefg";
alert(str.replace('>','&gt;'));
```

**UPD** Тут надо что-то вроде php-шного htmlspecialchars(). [Посмотрите, как это работает](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/xyNBU/).

```
<div id = "code">
    <p>ТЕКСТ</p>
    <span>UPS</span>
    <div>Hashcode</div>
</div>

<div id = "res"><strong>Результат: </strong></div>
<script>
function htmlspecialchars(text) {
    var chars = Array("&", "<", ">", '"', "'");
    var replacements = Array("&amp;", "&lt;", "&gt;", "&quot;", "'");
    for (var i=0; i<chars.length; i++)
    {
        var re = new RegExp(chars[i], "gi");
        if(re.test(text))
        {
            text = text.replace(re, replacements[i]);
        }
    }
    return text;
}

var content = $('#code').html();
var newStr = htmlspecialchars(content);
$('#res').append(newStr);
</script>
```

Comment: если допустим у меня в <div id = 'code'><p>ТЕКСТ</p></div> И мне надо поменять так чтоб поменялось на <div id = 'code'>&gt;p&gt;ТЕКСТ&lt;/p&gt;</div> то как быть?

Comment: @zhekonya, смотрите апдейт в ответе

Comment: оба варианта нерабочие. первый поменяет только один символ, второй вернет только содержание дива `#code` и тоже поменяет только по одному символу

Comment: Во-первых, первый вариант - был до уточнения. Во-вторых, именно содержимое дива#code и надо преобразовать в мнемоники. Прозорливый, но не внимательный.

Comment: @Deonis читаем внимательно коммент, и ищем разницу между

        $('#res').append(newStr); 
и 

        $('#code').html(newStr);

Comment: Ох, сударь, сделайте отдолжение - вместо того, чтоб искать за что придраться, просто ставьте мне минус и не утомляйте. Угу?

Comment: @Deonis ваш ответ не заслуживает минуса, а вот с невнимательностью надо бороться, сам этим страдаю.

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "<div id = 'code'><p>ТЕКСТ</p></div>";
console.log(str.replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;'));

// &lt;div id = 'code'&gt;&lt;p&gt;ТЕКСТ&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
```

**Решение вашего вопроса:**

```
var code = $('#code');
code.html(
  code.html()
  .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
  .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
)
```

Comment: @Deonis за что минус объясните пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

```
(function(w, d) {
    var t = d.createElement("div");
    w.htmlentities = function(s) {
        t.innerHTML = '';
        t.appendChild(d.createTextNode(s));
        return t.innerHTML;
    }
}(window, document));

var evilHtml = "<h1>evil html</h1>"
var evilScript = "<script> alert('evil script') </script>"

console.log(htmlentities( evilHtml ));
     // -> &lt;h1&gt;evil html&lt;/h1&gt;

console.log(htmlentities( evilScript ));
     // -> &lt;script&gt; alert('evil script') &lt;/script&gt;
```

Comment: Лол, обозвал всех велосипедистами. Плюс)

Answer (score 0):

```
str_replace(">","&gt;",$text);
```

Answer (score 0):

А чего все эту штуку забывают?)

```
var newStr = oldStr.split('<').join('&lt;');
```

Или:

```
var newStr = oldStr;
var replaces = [
  '<': '&lt;',
  '>': '&gt;' // , '&': '&amp;', etc etc...
];
for (var n in replaces)
  newStr = newStr.split(n).join(replaces[n]);
```

Comment: oldStr.split('<').join('&lt;');

Неадекватный по производительности и по читабельности, второй еще хуже первого.

Comment: replace регулярками в цикле лучше что ли?)